# Warning: Error in as.character: cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'character'

Tags: r, shiny

Why do I keep getting the error message: Warning: Error in as.character: cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'character'? I also updated later and httpuv, but they did not help. I wonder if the server has some functions. This is the code from 2014, and I am trying to reproduce it with updated data. Thank you!

## Main server function

```
server = shinyServer(function(input, output){

# Session selector 
Select_session <- reactive({
    df <- session

    # Search function
    # TODO: change from "or" to "and"
    if (length(input$keywords!=0)){
        kwd_pattern <- gsub(",", "|", input$keywords)
        df <- subset(df, grepl(kwd_pattern, df$descr, ignore.case = T))
    }

    # Date selector
    if (!is.null(input$DateRange)){
        df <- subset(df, 
                     as.Date(df$date)>=input$DateRange[1] & as.Date(df$date)<=input$DateRange[2])
    }

    # Area of interest selector
    if ("me" %in% input$IssueArea){
        df <- subset(df, df$me==1)
    }

    if ("nu" %in% input$IssueArea){
        df <- subset(df, df$nu==1)
    }

    if ("di" %in% input$IssueArea){
        df <- subset(df, df$di==1)
    }

    if ("hr" %in% input$IssueArea){
        df <- subset(df, df$hr==1)
    }

    if ("hr" %in% input$IssueArea){
        df <- subset(df, df$hr==1)
    }

    if ("ec" %in% input$IssueArea){
        df <- subset(df, df$ec==1)
    }

    if ("us" %in% input$IssueArea){
        df <- subset(df, df$importantvote==1)
    }

    return(df)
})

# Session table output 
output$sessionTable <- renderDataTable({
    df <- Select_session()
    if (length(input$keywords!=0)){
        kwd_pattern <- gsub(",", "|", input$keywords)
        df <- subset(df, grepl(kwd_pattern, df$descr, ignore.case = T))
    }

    # Vote title selector
    if (!is.null(input$voteTitle)){
        df <- subset(df, df$unres_title==input$voteTitle)
    }

    # Date selector
    df <- subset(df, 
                 as.Date(df$date)>=input$DateRange[1] & as.Date(df$date)<=input$DateRange[2])

    # Select only following variables in data table and downloaded csv file
    vars <- c("date","session","unres_title", "descr", "yes", "no", "abstain")
    df <- df[,vars]
    return(df)}, 
    # Turn off searching function
    # List length, 3 options: 5/25/all
    # Page Length, default = 5
    options = list(searching = FALSE,
                   lengthMenu = list(c(5, 25, -1), c('5', '25', 'All')),
                   pageLength = 5)
)

# Voting selector
Select_voting <- reactive({
    df <- vote

    # Link session data and vote data by rcid
    if (length(Select_session()$rcid)!=0){
        df <- subset(df, df$rcid %in% unique(Select_session()$rcid))
    }

    # Vote title selector
    if (!is.null(input$voteTitle)){
        df <- subset(df, df$unres_title==input$voteTitle)
    }

    return(df)
})

# Voting table output
output$votingTable <- renderDataTable({
    df <- vote
    # Select voting data based on rcid
    df <- subset(df, df$rcid %in% unique(Select_voting()$rcid))
    vars <- c("unres", "Country", "CABB", "Vote")
    df <- df[,vars]
}, 
options = list(pageLength = 10)
)

# Session data downloader
output$downloadSession <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "UN_Session.csv",
    content = function(file){
        vars <- c("session","unres_title", "date", "yes", "no", "abstain")
        df <- Select_session()[,vars]
        write.csv(df, file)
    }
)

# Voting data downloader
output$downloadVoting <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "UN_Voting.csv",
    content = function(file){
        vars <- c("unres", "Country", "CABB", "Vote")
        df <- Select_voting()[,vars]
        write.csv(df, file)
    }
)

# Map visualization
output$map <- renderPlot({
    if (length(unique(Select_voting()$rcid))==1){
        # Load map color
        color_for_map <- subset(colormatrix, 
                                colormatrix$breaksvalue %in% unique(Select_voting()$vote))

        # Main function to visualize map
        ggplot()+
            # Base map, fill=white, line=gray
            geom_map(data=World.points, 
                     map = World.points, 
                     aes(map_id=region), 
                     fill="#ecf0f1", color="white")+ 
            # Vote map, fill based on vote, line = white
            geom_map(data=Select_voting(),
                     map = World.points, 
                     aes(map_id=region, 
                         fill = as.character(vote)), 
                     color="white")+
            # Expand axis
            expand_limits(x = world_map$long, y = world_map$lat)+
            # Change fill color based on color matrix file
            scale_fill_manual(
                values=color_for_map$colors, 
                name="Vote",
                breaks=color_for_map$breaksvalue,
                labels=color_for_map$breakslabel)+
            # Stephen Few plot theme, require(ggthemes)
            theme_few()+
            # No axis line, axis text, axis title
            theme(axis.line=element_blank(),
                  axis.text.x=element_blank(),
                  axis.text.y=element_blank(),
                  axis.ticks=element_blank(),
                  axis.title.x=element_blank(),
                  axis.title.y=element_blank(),
                  #legend.position="none",
                  panel.background=element_blank(),
                  panel.border=element_blank(),
                  panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
                  panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
                  plot.background=element_blank())
    }

    # Map without vote title selection
    else if (length(input$voteTitle)==0){
        ggplot()+
            geom_map(data=World.points, 
                     map = World.points, 
                     aes(map_id=region), 
                     fill="#ecf0f1", 
                     color="white")+
            expand_limits(x = world_map$long, y = world_map$lat)+
            theme_few()+
            geom_text(aes(x = mean(world_map$long), 
                          y = mean(world_map$lat)), 
                          label="Select the vote title to view map",
                          size = 10, colour = "#3498db")+
            theme(axis.line=element_blank(), 
                  axis.text.x=element_blank(),
                  axis.text.y=element_blank(), 
                  axis.ticks=element_blank(),
                  axis.title.x=element_blank(),
                  axis.title.y=element_blank(),
                  legend.position="none",
                  panel.background=element_blank(),
                  panel.border=element_blank(),
                  panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
                  panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
                  plot.background=element_blank())
    }

    # Map without voting data
    else{
        ggplot() + 
            geom_map(data=World.points, map = World.points, aes(map_id=region), fill="#ecf0f1", color="white") +
            expand_limits(x = world_map$long, y = world_map$lat)+
            theme_few()+
            geom_text(aes(x = mean(world_map$long), y = mean(world_map$lat)), label="VOTING DATA UNAVAILABLE", size = 10, colour = "#3498db")+
            theme(axis.line=element_blank(),axis.text.x=element_blank(),
                  axis.text.y=element_blank(),axis.ticks=element_blank(),
                  axis.title.x=element_blank(),
                  axis.title.y=element_blank(),legend.position="none",
                  panel.background=element_blank(),panel.border=element_blank(),panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
                  panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),plot.background=element_blank())
    }

}, height = 400, width = 800)

# Title selection
output$TitleSelectUI <- renderUI({ 
    selectizeInput("voteTitle", "Select the vote title", 
                   choices = Select_session()$unres_title,
                   multiple = T,
                   options = list(maxItems = 1))
})

# Official document link
official_doc_link <- reactive({
    df <- Select_session()
    if (!is.null(input$voteTitle)){
            df <- subset(df, df$unres_title==input$voteTitle)
            if (df$session>30){
            # UN official document URL
            url_string <- paste("http://www.un.org/en/ga/search/view_doc.asp?symbol=%20A/RES/",
                                gsub("\\D", "",strsplit(df$unres[1], split = "/")[[1]][2]),
                                "/",
                                gsub("\\D", "",strsplit(df$unres[1], split = "/")[[1]][3]),
                                sep = "")
        }
        else {url_string = NULL}
    }
    else {
        url_string = NULL
    }
    return(url_string)
})

# Official document hyperlink
output$OfficialDoc <- renderUI({
    h5(a("Click to view official document at un.org", href = official_doc_link(), target="_blank"))
})
```

})

Comment: which line is causing it? This is a lot of code to try and go through... what troubleshooting steps have you taken to try and narrow down the issue?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to do `as.character(vote)`, however, `vote` is a passed back as part of a `tibble` from a reactive function (line 82), but on line 148, you are calling it as if it is a normal variable. You seem to do it correctly on line 134 where you are getting the unique values of the vote. Since `Select_voting()` appears to be a `tibble`, then you may be able to do: `as.character(Select_voting()$vote)` as you did above.